# Insert new paragraph after custom tag in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I've got a small TinyMCE plugin that takes selected text and wraps it in `<phone></phone>` tags.
It works as expected, however, when I start a new line after a line with `<phone></phone>` a new phone tag is created in that line automagically. I'd like to override this behaviour and get a `<p></p>` in that line instead.

Is there a way to tell Tiny that it should create paragraphs after phones?

Here's my plugin:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('example', {
        text: 'Phone',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            // Open window
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Add phone number',
                data: { phone_no: editor.selection.getContent() },
                body: [
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'phone_no', label: 'Phone number'}
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e) {
                    // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                    editor.setContent('<phone>' + e.data.phone_no + '</phone>');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's init:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "example",
    plugins: "example",
    extended_valid_elements : "phone",
    custom_elements: "phone",
    valid_children: "phone[#text]",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
            console.log('change event', e.level.content);
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: I've noticed a similar "problem" when hitting the enter key inside a ´<p class="someclass">`. Tinymce-4 seam to inherit last block in an automated way. Maybe a related issue here.

Comment: Have same issue when adding figure with figcaption, cannot add new paragraph below that